# Exponent rules, how can I simplify this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to simplify the expression $\frac{3x^2y^{-3}z}{12x^{-1}yz^3}$

I got $\frac{3x^2z}{12y^2z^3}$

Submitting my answer to the quiz and getting it wrong, I can see the correct answer is actually $\frac{x^3}{4y^4z^2}$

I was unsure how to get started or approach, but here's how I arrived at where I did:

$\frac{3x^2y^{-3}z}{12x^{-1}yz^3}$

(Get rid of the negative exponents by using power rule $x^{-n}$ = $\frac{1}{x^n}$)

$\frac{\frac{3x^2z}{y^3}}{\frac{12yz^3}{x}}$

(complex fraction, multiple with swapped numerator and denominator)

$\frac{3x^2z}{y^3}*\frac{12yz^3}{x}$

$\frac{3x^3z}{12y^2z^3}$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $\frac{x^3}{4y^4z^2}$ ? Seeking granular, spoon fed steps if possible?

Comment: ...except you _forgot_ to  "swap" the numerator and denominator of the denominator in the compound fraction.  You wanted $$  \frac{3x^2z}{y^3} \ · \ \frac{x}{12yz^3}  \ \ . $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the coefficients, we see that both $3$ and $12$ are divisible by $3$. So dividing both the top and bottom by $3$ gives us $1$ and $4$, so we have:
$$
\frac{x^2(\color{red}{y^{-3}})z}{4(\color{blue}{x^{-1}})yz^3}
$$

Next, let's get rid of negative exponents. Basically, we can make them positive and flip them to the other side:
$$
\frac{(\color{blue}{x^{1}})x^2z}{4(\color{red}{y^{3}})yz^3}
$$
Combine the exponents for like bases by adding together the exponents:
$$
\frac{x^3z}{4y^4z^3}
$$
Finally, for $z$, divide both the top and the bottom by $z$ to obtain:
$$
\frac{x^3}{4y^4z^2}
$$

Comment: Neat and clean answer +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you got wrong:

$\frac{\frac{3x^2z}{y^3}}{\frac{12yz^3}{x}}$

This is a complex fraction which can be written as

$\frac{3x^2z}{y^3}÷{\frac{12yz^3}{x}}$

Which is, $\frac{3x^2z}{y^3} *{\frac{x}{12yz^3}}$

You did not swap the numerator and denominator while simplifying

Now, using power rules and cancelling 12 with 3 you get

$\frac{x^3}{4y^4z^2}$